# Update nested JS objects without overwriting missing properties

Tags: javascript

> EDIT: Thanks 4 all the great, diverse answers - I chose the solution that worked for me even after I realized that I needed more requirements: I also needed new properties to be added and for it to work with arrays in objects  as well.

Here's what I wanna do: Update one object through another one.
Here are some constraints:

- Only properties that the new object has should be updated (and that the original object also has), the other properties should remain unchanged, NOT DELETED
- Nested objects should also be updated in the same way

My Problem is that I don't know how to easily do this for nested objects  because `typeof x === "object"` also returns true for Date objects for example.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
let originalObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 10),
  value: "100",
  subObj: {
    count: 55,
    val: null
  }
};

let updateObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 11),
  subObj: {
    val: 90
  }
};

let updateOrignal = (oObj, uObj) => {
  for (let prop in uObj) {
    if (uObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
      oObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      oObj[prop] = uObj[prop];
    }
  }
};

console.log(originalObj);
updateOrignal(originalObj, updateObj)
console.log(originalObj);
```

Currently my updated object looks like this:

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2021-02-10T23:00:00.000Z",
  "value": "100",
  "subObj": {
    "val": 90
  }
}
```

My goal:

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2021-02-10T23:00:00.000Z",
  "value": "100",
  "subObj": {
    "count": 55,
    "val": 90
  }
}
```

Comment: `updateObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` <= should use `uObj`.  Probably not the issue, but it is inconsistent.

Comment: Your logic is checking if the update object and the original object have the key to update.  I understand you don't want to delete keys, but if you require the key to be pre existing in both places, you're never going to add new ones.

Comment: @Taplar thx, I corrected it

Comment: @Taplar I didn' say I want to add new ones, and I don't. But also didn't say that I don't want it, so I get your point, updated my question^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution you need (from https://gist.github.com/ahtcx/0cd94e62691f539160b32ecda18af3d6), actually you can search on google "deep merge" or "recursively merge two javascript objects"

I added ES6 sintax {...obj} to be sure to clone objects before merging them

```js
let originalObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 10),
  value: "100",
  subObj: {
    count: 55,
    val: null
  }
};

let updateObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 11),
  subObj: {
    val: 90
  }
};

const merge = (target, source) => {
  // Iterate through `source` properties and if an `Object` set property to merge of `target` and `source` properties
  for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
    if (source[key] instanceof Object) Object.assign(source[key], merge(target[key], source[key]))
  }
  // Join `target` and modified `source`
  Object.assign(target || {}, source)
  return target
}

console.log(merge({ ...originalObj}, {...updateObj}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could test the constructor of the values like this:

```js
let originalObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 10),
  value: "100",
  subObj: {
    count: 55,
    val: null
  }
};

let updateObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 11),
  subObj: {
    val: 90
  }
};

let updateOriginal = (original, patch) => {
  Object.entries(patch).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    value && value.constructor === Object && patch[key]
      ? updateOriginal(original[key], patch[key])
      : (original[key] = patch[key]);
  });
}

updateOriginal(originalObj, updateObj);

console.log(originalObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursive approach with `reduce` method and `for..in` loop and also check if the type of object is `Date`. This solution will not work with arrays and also will not modify original data.

```js
let originalObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 10),
  value: "100",
  subObj: {
    count: 55,
    val: null
  }
};

let updateObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 11),
  subObj: {
    val: 90
  }
};

function update(o1, o2) {
  return Object.entries(o1).reduce((r, e) => {
    for (let p in o2) {
      if ([o1[p], o2[p]].every(o => typeof o === 'object')) {
        r[p] = o2[p] instanceof Date ? o2[p] : update(r[p], o2[p])
      } else {
        r[p] = o2[p]
      }
    }

    return r
  }, { ...o1 })
}

const result = update(originalObj, updateObj)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in the past. You can clean it up a little and customize for your purposes but the idea is as follows:

```js
let originalObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 10),
  value: "100",
  subObj: {
    count: 55,
    val: null
  }
};

let updateObj = {
  dateCreated: new Date(2021, 1, 11),
  subObj: {
    val: 90
  }
};

function mergeDeep(target, source) {
  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    for (const key in source) {
      if (isObject(source[key])) {
        if (!target[key]) {
          Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
        }
        mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    }
  }
}

function isObject(item) {
  return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

console.log(originalObj);
mergeDeep(originalObj, updateObj);
console.log(originalObj);
```